# Using base and this in constructor chaining

Tags: c#, constructor

Say there is a base class called `Employee` that looks like the following

```
public Employee(string name, int id, float pay)
    : this(name, 0, id, pay, "") { }
public Employee(string name, int age, int id, float pay, string ssn)
{
    // Better!  Use properties when setting class data.
    // This reduces the amount of duplicate error checks.
    Name = name;
    Age = age;
    ID = id;
    Pay = pay;
    SocialSecurityNumber = ssn;
}
```

And a class `Manager` which inherits from `Employee` with a constructor like

```
public Manager(string fullName, int age, int empID,
  float currPay, string ssn, int numbOfOpts)
    : base(fullName, age, empID, currPay, ssn)
{
    .
    StockOptions = numbOfOpts;
}
```

To the best my understanding, the `this` keyword is just like the `base` keyword only it applies to constructors in the same class.  My biggest question is, while reading a reference book, it says if you don't use the chaining the construction of a `Manager` object will include seven 'hits'.  Since Manager inherits from Employees, does this mean that every Manager object is 'born' as an Employee and then becomes a Manager later?  And after it is a manager you only have two fields to add instead of seven?

Comment: I've no idea what "will include seven 'hits'" is meant to mean. And if the only constructors for `Employee` are the two you've shown, you *have* to use chaining - if you don't explicitly invoke `base(...)`, the compiler will insert a call to the parameterless constructor of your base class - which would be an error if no such constructor exists.

Comment: i believe it's, per the book, the number of calls to the inherited initialization members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is it.

The contructor parameters flow from the bottom up, then the object is created from the top down.  It has to be like this in case your derived class need to access base class members in its constructor.

Answer (score 4):

In .NET, the complete object is created before any constructors get called. Next, the base constructor is called, then the derived class constructor.

So the answer is no - the manager object is not born as an employee and becomes a manager later. Rather, the manager object is born as a manager object ... before constructors get called.

BTW, in non-managed C++, it's the opposite, although enough memory is allocated for the derived class, the Employee object is created first (calling the Employee constructor) and any virtual methods called will result in despatching to the base class method bodies. Then the Manager class gets constructed.